# Visual Studio 2013 Coded UI Test

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

I am currently looking into UI testing with alternatives for Selenium, recently i made the switch to VS2013 from VS2012 and the first thing i notice is that, the Coded UI Test project template is missing.

Anyone has a clue why this is missing and / or i need to install something in addition or if some workaround exists to make it available again?

Comment: what version of VS2013? Also, Microsoft states that they have rather 'improved' coded ui. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn268304.aspx

Comment: @Aniket, Professional, the "improved" coded ui that is being mentioned on that page, is for Windows Store apps only, not for web i am afraid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate and Premium Editions have CodedUI test. See here for all the supported configuration details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380742.aspx

I am not sure if you can add it to Professional(I see no downloads listed for CUIT)

Comment: Ah, not sure why but i was pretty sure it was available in Professional too.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As Aniket mentioned, Coded UI is only available for the Ultimate and Premuim editions. There is also a Test pro edition that has a limited number of Testing tools. Some of them can be used to initially describe your tests and the later automate them with Coded UI.

The following links provides a feature comparison between the editions. Go to the Testing tools section, which specifies the availability of Coded UI in the specific editions:

http://www.visualstudio.com/en-US/products/compare-visual-studio-products-vs